# Adater keep reference to Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom Adapter and I want to keep a reference to its ListView as a private member variable in the Adapter. Is this going to create a memory leak? Neither the Adapter nor the ListView are static.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your custom adapter, do what ever you want with it!! It will not leak memory at all because you only store a reference to your listview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but won't ListView leak when stored in Adapter which instance is keept in Fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`?